# Reference not found - trying to make a submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm kinda new in ASP.Net - razor.  I already have done with my front page but as soon as I tried to make a submit button, it doesn't work.

I tried to do this manually, write the code down because it doesn't show up in Login.cshtml.cs

Button type="submit" id="submit"

In Login.cshtml.cs

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    //This one was written manually because won't show up
    protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "Your application description page.";
    }
}
```

I expect the output "Test", but nothing happen.

in another framework as soon I put a button, is created to code it.

Comment: It would be better to go through some tutorial first. I recommend this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Share your view page code(cshtml page).